# How can I solve x + 1 < 2 in Sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

in Mathematics, I can solve "x + 1 < 2" with:

```
Reduce[x + 1 < 2, x]
```

Can I do the same thing with SymPy? And How Can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use real=True to define a real symbol:

```
In [1]: x = symbols("x", real=True)

In [2]: solve(x + 1 < 2, x)
Out[2]: x < 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`solve()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html) function.

```
>>> from sympy.solvers import solve
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> solve(x + 1 < 2, x)
And(im(x) == 0, re(x) < -3)
```

Comment: I can get "x < 1" in Mathematics, how can I get it in SymPy?